# Javascript Regex, How to find trailing zeros in a string

Tags: javascript, regex

I wanna learn more of regex 
But the complexity of the patterns makes my learning difficult.

I need to find all trailing zeros in a string.
Can someone show me a pattern then explain how it works.

Comment: Have you tried a regex tutorial? E.g. https://regexone.com/ (there are a lot more)

Comment: @Wiktor Stribiżew, i only need to find all trailing zeros. Not replace them.

Comment: @Kathara i did tried a regex tutorial but i can only identify the pattern but not how it works

Comment: Yes, you want to find them, so `0+$` pattern in the linked thread is what you need.

Comment: @MichaelAngeloSison I suggest you use regex101.com and learn how it works ;) (I've had problems with regex as well, this might help too: https://www.cheatography.com/davechild/cheat-sheets/regular-expressions/)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try  `/[0]+$/g`

For example

```
"2342300".match(/[0]+$/); //["00"]
```

Explanation

- `[0]+` matches continous `0`s
- `$` at the end matches end of the input and ensures only `0`s at the end of the string is matched.

Comment: So why not just `/0+$/`?

Comment: @Derek朕會功夫 Yes that will match as well. I just find `[0]+` more readable than `0+`